# Kivy- kv language VKeyboard

Tags: python, widget, kivy, virtual-keyboard

I'd like to add VKeyboard widget for my app written using Kivy 1.9.0. I using Python 2.7.12. Is there a way to add this widget to application via kv language? Because while trying method below there is bug:  'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'

```
        Button:
            background_color:1,0,0,0.5
            text:'Next word'
            size_hint:.5,.2
            font_size:25
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5}
            on_press:root.word_dict()

        VKeyboard:
            layout:'layout.json'
```

**layout.json**

```
 { "title":"KeyboardPinyin", "description":"Keyboard using for writing pinyin characters", "cols":5, "rows":3, "normal_1":[ ["ā","ā","ā",1], ["ē","ē","ē",1], ["ī","ī","ī",1], ["ō","ō","ō",1], ["ū","ū","ū",1] ], "normal_2": [ ["á","á","á",1], ["é","é","é",1], ["í","í","í",1], ["ó","ó","ó",1], ["ú","ú","ú",1] ], "normal_3": [ ["ǎ","ǎ","ǎ",1], ["ě","ě","ě",1], ["ǐ","ǐ","ǐ",1], ["ǒ","ǒ","ǒ",1], ["ǔ","ǔ","ǔ",1] ], "normal_4": [ ["à","à","à",1], ["è","è","è",1], ["ì","ì","ì",1], ["ò","ò","ò",1], ["ù","ù","ù",1] ] }
```

Comment: it sounds like layout.json is not valid json ... make sure you follow their example .... or at least post layout.json

Comment: There's layout.json: {
"title":"KeyboardPinyin",
"description":"Keyboard using for writing pinyin characters",
"cols":5,
"rows":3,
"normal_1":[
["ā","ā","ā",1],
["ē","ē","ē",1],
["ī","ī","ī",1],
["ō","ō","ō",1],
["ū","ū","ū",1]
],
"normal_2":
[
["á","á","á",1],
["é","é","é",1],
["í","í","í",1],
["ó","ó","ó",1],
["ú","ú","ú",1]
],
"normal_3":
[
["ǎ","ǎ","ǎ",1],
["ě","ě","ě",1],
["ǐ","ǐ","ǐ",1],
["ǒ","ǒ","ǒ",1],
["ǔ","ǔ","ǔ",1]
],
"normal_4":
[
["à","à","à",1],
["è","è","è",1],
["ì","ì","ì",1],
["ò","ò","ò",1],
["ù","ù","ù",1]
]
}

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joran/.PyCharm50/config/scratches/scratch_33", line 3, in <module>
    data = json.load(open(os.path.expanduser("~/layout1.json")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

you cannot it tries to decode the input using utf8 ... you have non-utf8 characters in your json

you should instead use the unicode representation `"\u00e0"` etc  (or you must somehow specify the character encoding of the json ... I am not sure how you might do that offhand)

Comment: after writing characters in unicode problem still occurs.

Comment: What do you mean? Please post your solution for others or accept this one if it was right

Comment: I just made GridLayout (instead VKeyboard) with Buttons, which each containing character that I needed and puts that character to TextInput when is pressed. I know that it's not 'real' solution of the problem, but it at least works.